# Getting 'The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint' even when I'm trying to avoid references to the foreign key

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I have two tables tblPriceHeader and tblPriceDetail, with tblPriceDetail having a FK reference to tblPriceHeader. I'm trying to delete some duplicates from tblPriceHeader using the following query:

```
delete from tblPriceHeader
where rowguid in (
    select distinct ph.rowguid
    from tblPriceHeader ph
    left join tblPriceDetail pd on ph.EventID = pd.EventID
    where ph.EventID in (
        select EventID
        from tblPriceHeader
        group by EventID
        having count(EventID) > 1
    )
    and ph.RecID != pd.EventHeaderRecID
)
```

The last line is meant to only give me the dupes in tblPriceHeader where there is no actual reference in tblPriceDetail.

Comment: Please show the table schemas.

Comment: Maybe you're deleting more than the duplicates but also the "originals"? I think your query might be easier to debug if you use ROW_NUMBER PARTITION BY to figure out duplicates

Comment: I see that you're doing a left join between the header and detail tables but I don't see a predicate that looks anything like `pd.rowguid is null` to identify missing rows on that side of the join.

Comment: I will assume that `tblPriceDetail.EventHeaderRecID` is a FK reference to `tblPriceHeader.RecId`.  It appears your intent is to delete one or more `tblPriceHeader` that share the same `EventID`. Your `left join tblPriceDetail pd on ph.EventID = pd.EventID` and `and ph.RecID != pd.EventHeaderRecID` are effectively checking for "**any** `tblPriceDetail` row with the same `EventID` does not relate to the `tblPriceHeader` row under consideration". Perhaps instead of checking for "**any**", you intended to check for "**all**"? Note that this still would not explicitly check FK dependencies.

Comment: If you wish further assistance, please a detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish along with a minimal schema and sample data that demonstrates your issue.